# appendChild in JS not creating new node

Tags: javascript

Below is my code snippet. I want to add new list item depending on my conditions. All is going well except the fact that the script is not creating new bullet points and it is adding all the text into the same bullet point.

```
if(revenue2015 > revenue2016 && revenue2015!=0 && revenue2016!=0){
     per=(revenue2016-revenue2015)/revenue2015;
     revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue decreased by ("+(per*100)+"%) on YoY basis from 2015 to 2016.")));
}
else if(revenue2015 < revenue2016 && revenue2015!=0 && revenue2016!=0){
     per=(revenue2016-revenue2015)/revenue2015;
     revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue increased by "+(per*100)+"% on YoY basis from 2015 to 2016.")));
}
else if(revenue2015 == 0 || revenue2016 == 0)
{
    if(revenue2015 ==0 && revenue2016 == 0){
        revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue data for the both 2015 & 2016 are missing.")));
    }
    else if(revenue2015 ==0 && revenue2016 != 0){
        revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue data for 2015 is missing.")));
    }
    else if(revenue2016 ==0 && revenue2015 != 0){
        revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue data for 2016 is missing.")));
    }
}


if(revenue2016 > revenue2017 && revenue2016!=0 && revenue2017!=0){
     per=(revenue2017-revenue2016)/revenue2016;
     revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue decreased by ("+(per*100)+"%) on YoY basis from 2016 to 2017.")));
}
else if(revenue2016 < revenue2017 && revenue2016!=0 && revenue2017!=0){
     per=(revenue2017-revenue2016)/revenue2016;
     revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue increased by "+(per*100)+"% on YoY basis from 2016 to 2017.")));
}
else if(revenue2017 == 0)
{
        revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue data for 2017 is missing!!!")));
}
```

The output is

Revenue data for the both 2015 & 2016 are missing.Revenue data for 2017 is missing!!!

However, it should be in two separate bullet points and not the same line. Any solutions?

Comment: can you send full code for make clear vision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value returned by *appendChild* is the node that was appended, so when you do:

```
     revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue decreased by ("+(per*100)+"%) on YoY basis from 2015 to 2016.")));
```

the node that is appended to *revenuePoint* is the final text node, not the LI. So all you get is a concatenation of all the text nodes. You have to break it into separate statements like:

```
var li = revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li')); // returns the LI
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue decreased by (" +
               (per * 100) + "%) on YoY basis from 2015 to 2016.")); // returns the text node
```

though you might like to create a function that you just pass the root node and text, then it generates the LI and appends the text.

PS. In the original code, when the text node is appended to *revenuePoint*, it is detached from the LI it was initially appended to. The LI has nothing referencing it so is made available for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that following line will not work:
`revenuePoint.appendChild(document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Revenue data for 2017 is missing!!!")))`

You need must split like following way:

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Revenue data for 2017 is missing!!!")
li.appendChild(textNode);
revenuePoint.appendChild(li);
```